# SyncAdapter onPerformSync not triggered after requestSync

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I followed the guide from the docs on how to create a SyncAdapter, I think I have all the pieces in place but for some reason, it is not working.

This is my SyncAdapter:

```
public class MediaSyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    public static final long SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60L;
    public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES = 60L;
    public static final long SYNC_INTERVAL = SYNC_INTERVAL_IN_MINUTES * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;


    public MediaSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    public MediaSyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize, boolean allowParallelSyncs) {
        super(context, autoInitialize, allowParallelSyncs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle bundle, String s,
                              ContentProviderClient contentProviderClient, SyncResult syncResult) {

        Timber.e("IT HAPPENED");
        SyncService.getStartIntent(getContext());
    }

    public static void syncImmediately(Context context) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(getSyncAccount(context),
        context.getString(R.string.content_authority), bundle);
    }

    public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
        AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        Account newAccount = new Account(context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type));
        if (null == accountManager.getPassword(newAccount)) {

            if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
            return null;
            }

        }
        return newAccount;
    }
}
```

My stub provider:

```
public class StubProvider extends ContentProvider {
    /*
     * Always return true, indicating that the
     * provider loaded correctly.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }
    /*
     * Return no type for MIME type
     */
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * query() always returns no results
     *
     */
    @Override
    public Cursor query(
            Uri uri,
            String[] projection,
            String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) {
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * insert() always returns null (no URI)
     */
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * delete() always returns "no rows affected" (0)
     */
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
    /*
     * update() always returns "no rows affected" (0)
     */
    public int update(
            Uri uri,
            ContentValues values,
            String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The Service that triggers the adapter:

```
public class MediaService extends Service {

    private static MediaSyncAdapter mSyncAdapter = null;

    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

    public MediaService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (mSyncAdapter == null) {
                mSyncAdapter = new MediaSyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

My authentication service:

```
public class AuthenticatorService extends Service {

    // Instance field that stores the authenticator object
    private MediaAuthenticator mMediaAuthenticator;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Create a new authenticator object
        mMediaAuthenticator = new MediaAuthenticator(this);
    }
    /*
     * When the system binds to this Service to make the RPC call
     * return the authenticator's IBinder.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mMediaAuthenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}
```

My authenticator:

```
public class MediaAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    // Simple constructor
    public MediaAuthenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    // Editing properties is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r, String s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Don't add additional accounts
    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            String s,
            String s2,
            String[] strings,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }
    // Ignore attempts to confirm credentials
    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }
    // Getting an authentication token is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            String s,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Getting a label for the auth token is not supported
    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Updating user credentials is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            String s, Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Checking features for the account is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account, String[] strings) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

My relevant manifest entries:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.android.jventajas.app.moviegami.data.sync.AuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
            android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.android.jventajas.app.moviegami.data.sync.MediaService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.android.jventajas.app.moviegami.data.sync.StubProvider"
        android:authorities="com.android.jventajas.app.moviegami"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true"/>
```

My xml syncadapter definition:

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/content_authority"
    android:accountType="@string/sync_account_type"
    android:userVisible="false"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

My authenticator:

```
<account-authenticator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/sync_account_type"
    android:icon="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"
    android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

Does anyone know why onperformsync is not being triggered?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) We can't tell if you've messed up the authorities 2) Did the account get created? 3) Can you sync it manually from Settings > Accounts > ...? 4) You should throw `UnsupportedOperationException` from the unimplemented `ContentProvider` method, not return null since returning null is not specified in the `ContentProvider` contract.

Comment: I am getting same. and im unable to manually syn as well.